# CSV Writer inserting extra lines

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x

I'm having the same issue reported here, but the solutions aren't really related to the extra lines, they're pointing out that the original file is being opened incorrectly.

[Python 3.3 CSV.Writer writes extra blank rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16271236/python-3-3-csv-writer-writes-extra-blank-rows)

I have the same issue writing out a list, the following code

```
sample_data = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
with open('text.csv', 'w') as csvfile:                
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, dialect=csv.excel)
    writer.writerows(sample_data)
```

produces

```
1,2

3,4

5,6
```

Whilst changing the dialect to dialect=csv.unix_dialect (which as far as I can see only changes from lineterminator = '\r\n' to lineterminator = '\n'

produces the correct result

```
1,2
3,4
5,6
```

Am I doing something wrong, quite likely given I've just migrated to Py3.3

Comment: The last list should be split over 3 lines with no gaps. Sorry I cannot figure out how to do this on the forum

Comment: What platform is this? Linux, Mac, Windows?

Comment: ?  As mentioned in the linked question, in Python 3 you need to open csv files for writing using `open("text.csv", "w", newline="")`.  Are you saying you still get the extra lines when you use the correct parameters?

Comment: Hi DSM, I didn't notice the newline="" parameter, I was focused on the "w". using newline="" works thanks for both csv.unix_dialect and csv.excel (because presumably without newline="" the file object adds \r and then the csv writer adds with \n (unix_dialect) or \r\n (excel dialect)