# csv.writerows() puts newline after each row

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x

This is an example from the *O'Reilly Cookbook* (truncated dataset)

```
headers = ['Symbol','Price','Date','Time','Change','Volume']
rows = [{'Symbol': 'AA', 'Volume': 181800, 'Change': -0.18,
         'Time': '9:36am', 'Date': '6/11/2007', 'Price': 39.48},
        {'Symbol': 'AIG', 'Volume': 195500, 'Change': -0.15,
         'Time': '9:36am', 'Date': '6/11/2007', 'Price': 71.38} ]

with open('stocks2.csv','w') as f:
    f_csv = csv.DictWriter(f, headers)
    f_csv.writeheader()
    f_csv.writerows(rows)
```

the output file has a `\n` at the end of each line, and apparently one more at the end.  When I bring it into Excel, I get blank lines between each row.   The same if I open it with Notepad++.

But, if I `more` if from a command line, the `\n` don't show up.

I saw another Q&A about a `\n` at the end of a file - but this one is about a `\n` at the end of each line.   (And I don't see why `more` doesn't give the `\n`.)

I plan to bring the file into OpenOffice Calc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python 3.3 CSV.Writer writes extra blank rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16271236/python-3-3-csv-writer-writes-extra-blank-rows)

Comment: Voted to close as duplicate; as explained in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16271236/python-3-3-csv-writer-writes-extra-blank-rows) question (and in the csv docs), you need `newline=''` in the `open`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This problem occurs only with Python on Windows.

In Python v3, you need to add `newline=''` in the open call per:

[Python 3.3 CSV.Writer writes extra blank rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16271236/python-3-3-csv-writer-writes-extra-blank-rows)

On Python v2, you need to open the file as binary with "b" in your open() call before passing to csv

Changing the line

```
with open('stocks2.csv','w') as f:
```

to:

```
with open('stocks2.csv','wb') as f:
```

will fix the problem

More info about the issue here:

[CSV in Python adding an extra carriage return, on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191528/csv-in-python-adding-extra-carriage-return)

Answer (score 20):

I came across this issue on windows for Python 3. I tried changing newline parameter while opening file and it worked properly with `newline=''`.

Add `newline=''` to [open()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) method as follows:

```
with open('stocks2.csv','w', newline='') as f:
    f_csv = csv.DictWriter(f, headers)
    f_csv.writeheader()
    f_csv.writerows(rows)
```

It will work as charm.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 7):

It's an extra carriage return, and this is a Windows-specific issue not related to Python 2/3 differences. If you open up your file in Notepad++ and enable `Show all characters`, you'll see the following:

```
Symbol,Price,Date,Time,Change,Volume[CR]
[CR][LF]
AA,39.48,6/11/2007,9:36am,-0.18,181800[CR]
[CR][LF]
AIG,71.38,6/11/2007,9:36am,-0.15,195500[CR]
[CR][LF]
```

This is because Python on Windows is translating your line ending from `'\n'` to `'\r\n'`, while the `writerows()` function is already adding `'\r\n'` to the end of every line. What's happening:

1. csv.writerows() writes the appropriate row of data, and then ends the line with `'\r\n'`
2. Python's internal handling (because you're on Windows) sees the end of line '`\n`' and thinks it needs to change that to `'\r\n'`. So you get the `'\r\r\n'`.

The reason you don't see printing to the console have issues is because it's not detecting the extra `'\r'` as a new line, where as Excel and Notepad++ are.

For Python 3, you should be using the `newline=''` option as documented here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html.

> csv.writer(csvfile, dialect='excel', **fmtparams)
>
> Return a writer object responsible for converting the user’s data into delimited strings on the given file-like object. csvfile can be any object with a write() method. **If csvfile is a file object, it should be opened with newline='' [1].**

Comment: Thank you for the explanation +1

Answer (score 2):

I have had the same problem, Om Prakash's fix nearly worked for me, but I am writing a series of strings inside a for loop rather than a list, for me it was only solved as an append instead of w, and an \n instead of '':

```
with open('stocks2.csv','a', newline='\n') as f:
    f_csv = csv.DictWriter(f, headers)
    f_csv.writeheader()
    f_csv.writerows(rows)
```

Answer (score 2):

May help changing the "lineterminator" parameter as in:

```
csv.writer(<yourfile>,delimiter="\n",lineterminator="\n")
```