# More '\n' when write csv file using python

Tags: python

I want to write my data crawl to .csv file, but it have more '\n'. This is my code:

```
for data in soup.find_all('b', {'class' : 'tur highlight'}):
        write.writerow([word, data.get_text()])
```

And this is the result:

[image]

How to remove the blank rows? I use python 3.5

Comment: try adding `newline=''` when you open the file to write to or open it with "wb" instead of "w"

Comment: It's wright. Thank you.

Comment: no problem, I added some reference to my answer if you want to check it out @RiefSapthana

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this problems occurs when using python on windows:

if you're using Python 3.x, add this parameter when opening the file to write to:

```
newline=''
```

example:

```
with open('test_csv.csv','w',newline='') as file:
```

if you're using Python 2, open the file using `"wb"` instead of `"w"`.

```
with open('test_csv.csv','wb') as file:
```

reference : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30929363/csv-writerows-puts-newline-after-each-row)

Hope this was helpful.

Answer (score 2):

you can try this

```
for data in soup.find_all('b', {'class' : 'tur highlight'}):
        if word == '\n' and data.get_text() == '\n':
           pass
        else:
           write.writerow([word, data.get_text()])
```

or you can use

```
with open('test_csv.csv','w',newline='') as file:
```

for python 3

and

```
with open('test_csv.csv','wb') as file:
```

for python2