# Python Tkinter save file as CSV creating extra spaces

Tags: python, csv, tkinter

Normally when I open a CSV file in Python, I need to use:

```
with open(filename, newline='', mode='w') as f:
```

And if I don't have that *newline=''* in there, it creates an empty line between each line in my CSV. However, I am using Tkinter to save the file, so I have:

```
new_filename = asksaveasfile(mode='w', defaultextension='.csv')
```

Since "new_filename" is already open, I can't do the "open" command to indicate the newline='' in there. If I try opening it again, I get an error. So how do I get rid of the extra spaces in this case?

Thanks for your help and patience.

Comment: It's bizarre that you have to use the `newline` argument.  Are you sure that whatever viewer you're using isn't misinterpreting, for example `\r\n` as two newlines, or that your data doesn't have newlines already in it?  I've never had that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have some other problem regarding the new line parameter - I don't have to use it at all here. But for your tkinter problem, you can use `asksaveasfilename` instead. That returns the selected file name, then you can open it in any way you want.

Comment: The newline parameter seems fairly common, I've encountered many other Stack Overflow posts about it. Here's just a couple examples:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191528/csv-in-python-adding-an-extra-carriage-return
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30929363/csv-writerows-puts-newline-after-each-row

I'm not sure I follow what you mean by use "asksaveasfile" instead? I already am using it, as provided in the code I showed above. What would I use it instead of?

Comment: `asksaveasfilename` @Emac

Comment: Thanks, I missed that key word "name" ... and that fixed it! Much thanks.