# python adds extra blank line when writing to CSV

Tags: python, csv, file-writing

so a friend and I are working on a game in python. However, when we get the code to write out to the leaderboard, stored as an external file of the csv filetype, it always seems to add a blank line inbetween inputs.

[image]

the code is as follows:

```
def leaderBoardWrite(winnerName,winnerScore):
    with open('leaderboard.csv', mode='a') as leaderboard:
        winnerScoreSort = "{:03d}".format(winnerScore)
        print(winnerScoreSort)
        leaderboardWrite = csv.writer(leaderboard, delimiter=',')
        leaderboardWrite.writerow([winnerScoreSort,winnerName]) ## This writes over the leaderboard, adding the newest score into it.
    leaderBoardRead()
```

any advice?

thanks,

EDIT: since some people want a broader spec of the code, I will quickly forward it all so you have a full method of reproducing the code

```
## This is the start of the Dice game, look below at all of the comments to see what I have done once I have coded it.
## The next lines of code import all the nessasory modules for the program to run.
## The CSV Module is for the scoreboard
## Time is for the delays
## Random is for the
## Os is to clear the shell once the program has runself.
import csv,time,random,os
Complete = False ## Sets complete to false because the game has not begun
rounds = 0 ## Sets the rounds to 0 becasue game has not begun
playerOneScore = 000 ## Sets the player one score to 0 because they have not stated scoring yet
playerTwoScore = 000 ## Sets the player two score to 0 because they have not stated scoring yet
dice = [1,2,3,4,5,6] ## All the possible dice numbers
print("""
__          __  _                            _    _               _
\ \        / / | |                          | |  | |             | |
 \ \  /\  / /__| | ___ ___  _ __ ___   ___  | |  | |___  ___ _ __| |
  \ \/  \/ / _ \ |/ __/ _ \| '_ ` _ \ / _ \ | |  | / __|/ _ \ '__| |
   \  /\  /  __/ | (_| (_) | | | | | |  __/ | |__| \__ \  __/ |  |_|
    \/  \/ \___|_|\___\___/|_| |_| |_|\___|  \____/|___/\___|_|  (_) V.1.0.2
""")
time.sleep(1) ##Delay between welcome user and rules
print ("Welcome to my dice game! It is very simple to start playing.\nInput your username and password that were given to you and then type yes to verify you want to play (Please note 2 users both need to do this)\nBoth players will roll the dice twice\nThe totals of the rolls will be added to your net score\nIf your total is ODD, you will lose 5 points off of your overall score\nIf your total is EVEN, you will gain 10 points!\nIf you roll a double, the game will re-roll for you and you will gain the number of points rolled added to your score.\nThe winner is the person who has the most points at the end of the 5 rounds, once you have finished playing, you can see a leaderboard of players who have scored the most points.\nHave fun and good luck!")##Rules will be shown once at the start, straight after rules it will show the time delay.
print ("") ## Space between rules and dice delay
time.sleep(1) ## Delay between rules and dice delay
def PlayerOne(userOneName,playerOneScore,dice,delay): ## The function for Player One to start rolling and scoring
    input("[{}] When you are ready, press the ENTER key to roll the dice!".format(userOneName))
    diceOneRoll = dice[random.randint(0,len(dice)-1)] ## Rolls the first dice
    diceTwoRoll = dice[random.randint(0,len(dice)-1)] ## Rols the seccond dice
    total = diceOneRoll + diceTwoRoll ## Adds the scores from both dice rolls together
    if diceOneRoll == diceTwoRoll: ## Checks if both os the dice rolls were the same
        print("[{}] You have rolled a double, you get another roll!".format(userOneName))
        temp = PlayerOneReRoll(userOneName,dice) ## Calls a function to roll an extra die
        print("[{}] You scored {} from the reroll".format(userOneName,temp))
        playerOneScoreReturn = total + temp ## Adds the score of the reroll to their total score
    elif total % 2 == 0: ## Checks if the total of the two dice is even
        print("[{}] Your total was even, take an extra 10 points".format(userOneName))
        playerOneScoreReturn = total + 10
        pass
    elif total % 2 ==1: ## Checks if the total of the two dice is odd
        print("[{}] You have scored an odd number, you lose 5 points".format(userOneName))
        if playerOneScore-5 <0:
            playerOneScoreReturn = 0
        else:
            playerOneScoreReturn = -5

    else:
        pass
    time.sleep(delay)
    print("[{}] You scored {}".format(userOneName,total))
    time.sleep(delay)
    print("[{}] Your total score is {}".format(userOneName,playerOneScore+playerOneScoreReturn))
    return playerOneScoreReturn

def PlayerTwo(userTwoName,playerTwoScore,dice,delay):
    input("\n[{}] When you are ready, press the ENTER key to roll the dice!".format(userTwoName))
    diceOneRoll = dice[random.randint(0,len(dice)-1)]
    diceTwoRoll = dice[random.randint(0,len(dice)-1)]
    total = diceOneRoll + diceTwoRoll
    if diceOneRoll == diceTwoRoll:
        print("[{}] You have rolled a double, you get another roll!".format(userTwoName))
        temp = PlayerTwoReRoll(userTwoName,dice)
        print("[{}] You scored {} from the reroll".format(userTwoName,temp))
        playerTwoScoreReturn = total + temp
    elif total % 2 == 0:
        print("[{}] Your total was even, take an extra 10 points".format(userTwoName))
        playerTwoScoreReturn = total + 10
        pass
    elif total % 2 ==1:
        print("[{}] You have scored an odd number, you lose 5 points".format(userTwoName))
        if playerTwoScore-5 <0:
            playerTwoScoreReturn = 0
        else:
            playerTwoScoreReturn = -5
    else:
        pass
    time.sleep(delay)
    print("[{}] You scored {}".format(userTwoName,total))
    time.sleep(delay)
    print("[{}] Your total score is {}".format(userTwoName,playerTwoScore+playerTwoScoreReturn))
    return playerTwoScoreReturn

def PlayerOneReRoll(userOneName,dice):
    input("[{}] Ready to roll the dice again? Press ENTER key to roll.".format(userOneName))
    diceOneRoll = dice[random.randint(0,len(dice)-1)]
    total = diceOneRoll
    return total

def PlayerTwoReRoll(userTwoName,dice):
    input("[{}] ".format(userTwoName))
    diceOneRoll = dice[random.randint(0,len(dice)-1)]
    total = diceOneRoll
    return total

def main(userOneName,userTwoName,rounds,playerOneScore,playerTwoScore,Complete):
    print("\nRound [{}/5]\n".format(rounds))
    playerOneScoreTemp = PlayerOne(userOneName,playerOneScore,dice,delay)
    playerTwoScoreTemp = PlayerTwo(userTwoName,playerTwoScore,dice,delay)
    return playerOneScoreTemp,playerTwoScoreTemp

def draw(userOneName,userTwoName,dice,Complete):
    print("draw")
    playerOneScoreTemp = PlayerOneReRoll(userOneName,dice)
    playerTwoScoreTemp = PlayerTwoReRoll(userTwoName,dice)
    print("p1 = ",playerOneScoreTemp,"p2 = ",playerTwoScoreTemp)
    checkForWinner(userOneName,userTwoName,Complete,playerOneScoreTemp,playerTwoScoreTemp)

def checkForWinner(userOneName,userTwoName,Complete,playerOneScore,playerTwoScore):
    if Complete == True:
        if playerOneScore > playerTwoScore:
            print("\n[{}] You win with a score of {}. Well done".format(userOneName,playerOneScore))
            tmp = playerOneScore
            leaderBoardWrite(userOneName,tmp)
        elif playerTwoScore > playerOneScore:
            print("\n[{}] You win with a score of {}. Well done".format(userTwoName,playerTwoScore))
            tmp = playerTwoScore
            leaderBoardWrite(userTwoName,tmp)
        elif playerOneScore == playerTwoScore:
            print("\n[Both] It's come to a draw, play one last round to see who the ultimate champion is!" )
            draw(userOneName,userTwoName,dice,Complete)
        else:
            pass
    else:
        pass

def leaderBoardWrite(winnerName,winnerScore):
    with open('leaderboard.csv', mode='a') as leaderboard:
        winnerScoreSort = "{:03d}".format(winnerScore)
        leaderboardWrite = csv.writer(leaderboard, delimiter=',')
        leaderboardWrite.writerow([winnerScoreSort,winnerName]) ## This writes over the leaderboard, adding the newest score into it.
    leaderBoardRead()

def leaderBoardRead():## Shows the ASCII text of "Leaderboard"
    print (""" 
 _      ______          _____  ______ _____  ____   ____          _____  _____  
| |    |  ____|   /\   |  __ \|  ____|  __ \|  _ \ / __ \   /\   |  __ \|  __ \ 
| |    | |__     /  \  | |  | | |__  | |__) | |_) | |  | | /  \  | |__) | |  | |
| |    |  __|   / /\ \ | |  | |  __| |  _  /|  _ <| |  | |/ /\ \ |  _  /| |  | |
| |____| |____ / ____ \| |__| | |____| | \ \| |_) | |__| / ____ \| | \ \| |__| |
|______|______/_/    \_\_____/|______|_|  \_\____/ \____/_/    \_\_|  \_\_____/
""")
    data = open('leaderboard.csv')
    for row in sorted(csv.reader(data)):
        print(row) ## This reads the leaderboard and allows it to be shown in the code

delay = int(input("Please input a time delay for the dice to roll?\n: "))

## User One Authorisation
with open("logins.csv", newline= '') as csvnames:
    authentication = csv.reader(csvnames, delimiter=",")
    logins = list(authentication)

while True:
    print("Welcome user one!")
    userNameInput = input("Please input your username? \n: ")
    userPasswordInput = input("Please input your password? \n: ")

    for i in range(len(logins)):
        if userNameInput == logins[i][0] and userPasswordInput == logins[i][1]:
            userOneName = logins[i][0]
            userOneAuthorised = True
            break
        else:
            userOneAuthorised = False

    if userOneAuthorised == False:
        print("Sorry {}, you aren't authorised so run this task! \nPlease contact your System Administrator".format(userNameInput))
    else:
        try:
            ready = input("Welcome {}, you have been Authorised. Are you ready to play? (Please type **yes** or **no**) \n:_ ".format(userOneName))
            if ready[0].lower() == "y":
                userOneAuthorised = True
                break
            else:
                print("Please come back later, the game will be waiting for you!")
        except:
            pass

## User Two Authorisation
while True:
    print("Welcome user 2!")
    userNameInput = input("What is your username? \n: ")
    userPasswordInput = input("What is your password? \n: ")

    for i in range(len(logins)):
        if userNameInput == logins[i][0] and userPasswordInput == logins[i][1]:
            userTwoName = logins[i][0]
            userTwoAuthorised = True
            break
        else:
            userTwoAuthorised = False

    if userTwoAuthorised == False:
        print("Sorry {}, you aren't authorised so run this task! \nPlease contact your System Administrator".format(userNameInput))
    else:
        ready = input("Welcome {}, you have been Authorised. Are you ready to play? (Please type **yes** or **no**) \n:_ ".format(userTwoName))
        try:
            if ready[0].lower() == "y":
                userTwoAuthorised = True
                break
            else:
                print("Please come back later, the game will be waiting for you!")
        except:
            pass



if userOneAuthorised == True and userTwoAuthorised == True:
    print("Starting")
    for i in range(1,6):
        roundNums = main(userOneName,userTwoName,i,playerOneScore,playerTwoScore,Complete)
        playerOneScore+=roundNums[0]
        playerTwoScore+=roundNums[1]
        if i == 5:
            Complete = True
        else:
            pass
        checkForWinner(userOneName,userTwoName,Complete,playerOneScore,playerTwoScore)
else:
    pass

time.sleep(4)
```

sorry it's in such an awkward order, my friend seems to like ordering things funny.
thanks for all advice so far.

Comment: You are creating a new `csv.writer` for each line. That could be the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I remove a trailing newline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275018/how-can-i-remove-a-trailing-newline)

Comment: Could you share more of your program? I’d like to take a look at the broader design, and be able to run it (see: [mcve]). Also, variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Comment: That’s not a blank row, by the way. That’s an empty CSV row/row with no data, right? Finally, please share data/code as text in the post itself, not as an image.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [csv.writerows() puts newline after each row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30929363/csv-writerows-puts-newline-after-each-row)

Comment: hi, for anyone asking about more code, I have included the entire code for you to look at, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem before. I wound up writing a macro to delete the blank lines. I would recommend putting all the details you want per row into a map, appending the map to a list, and converting the list of maps to a dataframe using pandas. Then use the df.to_csv(filename) function to paste it into a spreadsheet.

If you need to continually append to the spreadsheet, then all you have to do is read the csv using pandas.read_csv(filename), creating the dataframe above, appending to what you currently have, and then use to_csv. The only thing you need to make sure is that to_csv adds an index column when it prints, so make sure that you reduce the dataframe to only the columns you need before appending. It won't break anything, but it will make the data stored in the spreadsheet a tad messier.

Good Luck!

Comment: I would do this, but unfortunately, due to the way I am coding, I am not able to install bonus modules such as pandas. It's one of the things about the code. We can use only base modules.