# how to remove blank lines from a csv file created using python

Tags: python, csv

We are creating a subfile from a big csv file. The subfile contains only those rows which have their first column's value as D1:

```
import csv
with open('input.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:

     reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='|', quotechar='|')

     writer1 = csv.writer(open('output.csv', 'w'), delimiter = ' ')

     for row in reader:
         a = row[0]
         row  =  '|'.join(row)
         if (a=='D1'):
                 writer1.writerow(row)
```

This code gives 2 issues:

1. A Blank line comes after every row in new csv file
2. Every word has extra spaces between it's letters. So, "Hello" becomes `"H e l l o"`.

Comment: Check for `automatic newline conversion` for `open()` (which OS are you on?). Provide sample data and ouput.

Comment: See also (not a duplicate): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29840849/writing-a-csv-file-in-python-that-works-for-both-python-2-7-and-python-3-3-in/29841468#29841468

Comment: The extra spaces sounds like you are using a string as a sequence (like a list or a tuple).

Comment: why are you doing `row  =  '|'.join(row)` ? you could just set `delimiter = '|'` in the writer and write the row directly

Comment: Thanks Pedru. This has solved the issue where "Hello" was becoming "H e l l o". Now just need to remove blank lines that are coming after every row in the new csv file.

Comment: The blank lines were removed after changing the write mode from "w" to "wb". Thanks everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code runs fine:

```
import csv
with open('input.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:

     reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='|', quotechar='|')

     writer1 = csv.writer(open('output.csv', 'wb'), delimiter = '|')

     for row in reader:
         a = row[0]
         if (a=='D1'):
                 writer1.writerow(row)
```

Thanks to Pedru

Answer (score 0):

From python csv docs..

> ```
> import csv
> with open('eggs.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
>     spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ',
>                             quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
>     spamwriter.writerow(['Spam'] * 5 + ['Baked Beans'])
>     spamwriter.writerow(['Spam', 'Lovely Spam', 'Wonderful Spam'])
> ```

So it seems that You have to use lists `['Spam']` with `spamwriter.writerow`... If its not list, this method `writerow` is creating its own list from iterable input like this:

```
>>> a = 'ala ma kota'
>>> list(a)
['a', 'l', 'a', ' ', 'm', 'a', ' ', 'k', 'o', 't', 'a']
```