# Python out of range on CSV after os functions

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to make a program that takes questions from a CSV file then asks them but weighted by their score. The lowest scored ones go first.

To do this I have a sort function.

```
def sort_records(csv_filename, sorted_file):
    with open(csv_filename, 'r') as i, open(sorted_file, 'w') as o:
        reader = csv.reader(i, delimiter = ',')
        writer = csv.writer(o, delimiter=',')
        writer.writerow(next(reader)) # header row
        writer.writerows(sorted(reader, key=operator.itemgetter(0)))
```

This works the first time, no problem.

But when there are no more questions to be asked and if the user decides to run the program again, it takes the files that have been written to (new_filename as well as another called answer_file) and deletes the original file and sorted file (file, sorted_file) then renames the updated file (answer_file) to just 'file'

```
def end(file, updated_file, sorted_file):
    ans_ok = False
    while ans_ok == False:
        ans = input("That's all folks... go again? Y/N: ")
        ans.upper()
        if ans == 'N':
            print("Press Enter to Exit...")
            input(" ")
            ans_ok = True
        elif ans == 'Y':
            os.remove(file)
            os.remove(newfile)
            os.rename(updated_file,file)
            print("\n Ok!\n")
            main()
```

And when I try to run the main function again it works and subsequently runs the 
sort_records function with the updated file that had just been renamed but that comes up with:

```
line 24, in sort_records
writer.writerows(sorted(reader, key=operator.itemgetter(0)))
IndexError: list index out of range
```

**EDIT**. This is the main function calling both of these

```
def main():
    path_ok = False
    while path_ok == False:
        try:
            file = input("Subject File: ")
            sorted_file = file[:-4]+'_sorted.sar'
            sort_records(file,sorted_file)
            path_ok = True
        except IOError:
            print("\tFile not found. Please input valid filename or path")

    updated_file = sorted_file[:-4]+'_final.sar'
    rownum = 0
    with open(newfile) as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        for row in reader:
            rownum+=1
            ask_question(row,updated_file,reader,sorted_file,file,rownum)
    end(file, updated_file, sorted_file)
```

Main is the first function called in the program also

**UPDATE**
I have found that by comparing the two files' text outside of notepad, the new file generated by the program looks like this:
[The text in both files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/grVzY.png)

Notepad did not show this for some reason.

Now I have another question:

***How do I write to a CSV file in Python without it automatically putting a blank line in-between lines being written?***

Comment: Add a code from where you calling `end` and `sort_records` functions

Comment: Ok, have done thank you

Comment: Not at the start, I had no idea when posting only at the end did I realise the problem was that there was a blank line between each line, see my answer for link to that question. I left the whole question here so that anyone with a similar problem (it may happen) can see this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, sorted. Turns out that was the case, story over :)

Second question answered by: [Why does CSV file contain a blank line in between each data line when outputting with Dictwriter in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8746908/why-does-csv-file-contain-a-blank-line-in-between-each-data-line-when-outputting)

Thanks Stackoverflow!