# download both xls and csv files from ftp

Tags: php, excel, laravel, csv, ftp

I am using [harishanchu](https://github.com/harishanchu/Laravel-FTP) laravel package for transfer xls files in FTP_BINARY mode and csv files in FTP_ASCII mode to ftp.

my clients connect to ftp through windows File Explorer, and i don't know what default transfer mode is in file explorer. they download xls files successfully but when download csv files, there is a blank line between each csv row.

what's the problem with downloading csv files and how to fix this?

tnx

Comment: Did you try to transfer csv as binary?

Comment: [Why does CSV file contain a blank line in between each data line when outputting with Dictwriter in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8747107/3226121). Maybe something there will help to point you in the right direction